# Class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class [B (java.lang.String and [B are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Tags: jackson, type-conversion, objectmapper

I am using Spring Boot version 2.4.1 and am attempting to convert an Object to JSON using Jackson ObjectMapper. The Object I'm converting is part of a Jar that was provided to me, so I don't have full visibility into in and cannot modify it.

The ultimate goal is to send this JSON using `JmsTemplate.convertAndSend()` method.

I am getting the following error (stack-trace at the bottom of the question):

```
Class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class [B (java.lang.String and [B are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

My messageConverter class:

```java
@Component
public class FooMessageConverter implements MessageConverter{
    
     private static final Logger LOGGER =
              LoggerFactory.getLogger(FooMessageConverter.class);

          ObjectMapper mapper;
          
          public FooMessageConverter() {
                mapper = new ObjectMapper();
              }
          
          @Override
          public Message toMessage(Object object, Session session)
              throws JMSException {
              MyObjectMessage msg = (MyObjectMessage) object;
              String payload = null;
              try {
                  payload = mapper.writeValueAsString(msg);
                  LOGGER.info("outbound ='{}'", payload);
              } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                  LOGGER.error("error converting form MyObjectMessage", e);
              }

              TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
              message.setText(payload);

            return message;
          }

        @Override
        public Object fromMessage(Message message) throws JMSException, MessageConversionException {
...
}
```

MessageSender class:

```java
@Service
public class FooMessageSender {
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FooMessageSender.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public void send(String queue, MyObjectMessage aMessage) {
        log.info("sending with convertAndSend() to queue <" + aMessage + ">");
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, aMessage);
    }
}
```

As I ran through a debugger, I see that some of MyObjectMessage properties are successfully serialized, but other properties fail during serialization process. I can't see inside the method itself, but I see that serialization fails when serializer is trying to invoke a "getter" method for that property from the hidden class. I would appreciate any pointers. Thank you!

Stack-trace:

```
31:47.945 ERROR [main                           ] [FooMessageConverter                                   ] error converting form MyObjectMessage.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class [B (java.lang.String and [B are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') (through reference chain: com.package.MyObjectMessage["payloadByteArrayOverflow"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:397)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:356)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:316)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:763)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._writeValueAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4409)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3663)
    at com.company.FooMessageConverter.toMessage(FooMessageConverter.java:37)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.lambda$convertAndSend$5(JmsTemplate.java:661)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:604)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.lambda$send$3(JmsTemplate.java:586)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:504)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:661)
    at com.company.FooMessageSender.send(FooMessageSender.java:21)
    at com.company.Application.run(Application.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:785)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298)
    at com.company.Application.main(Application.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class [B (java.lang.String and [B are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.package.MyObjectMessage.getPayloadByteArrayOverflow(MyObjectMessage.java:2388)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:689)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
 - com.company.FooMessageConverter - FooMessageConverter.java:40
```